# JavaFX 8 initialize method

Tags: java, javafx-8

So I am trying to do a chat type program using JavaFX for the GUI. I have it so a class that acts as a server will loop and keep adding client connections to it.

```
public void serverconnection()
{
    // portnumber was saved from constructor
    try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(this.portnumber))
    {
        // loop is a bool set to true
        while (loop) 
        {
            // this class extends Thread and has its own overwritten start method
            new myclass(socket.accept()).start();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.exit(404);
    }
 }
```

so the problem is (I am assuming) was, this loop keeps looping until the program closes. but since I was calling this within the JavaFX's initialize method

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    // constructor, nothing here is needed for this post
    myclass z = new myclass(45234);
    // problem here, since this has a  loop, but
    z.serverconnection();
    // gui wont load till after this is done
    // but serverconnection is only done after program ends
}
```

the problem with this is, apparently, the GUI will not load until AFTER initialize has finished, but it will not finish until program closes. After google searching, I could not find any fix for this. I need a way to call a method that will do all this, AFTER initialize method has finished. My client side class is similar to this, but the methods to connect on that are activated on events when clicking a login button. For this serverside one, I am trying to start without any interaction with the user. so is there a way to call a method or make this work AFTER initialize method has ran?

Comment: Have you considered adding a button in UI, clicking on which will call this method?

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj I wanted to try to avoid that, but if their is no other way I will add one

Comment: Using Java's concurrency feature FutureTask, you can execute tasks later. See if that works for you. If it doesn't, you need to allow initialize() to complete. So, adding a button would become necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to run this loop in a thread, so do something like

```
Thread t = new Thread(z::serverconnection)
t.start()
```

If you do this at the end of your `initialization()` method, it will run exactly then.

This will start a thread which runs forever; you might want to add a feature for interrupting the thread when the program is supposed to be terminated.

Remember that for changing anything in the GUI you need to sumbit a task via [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-). This is because the GUI may only be modified from within that one thread. So in order to modify anything, you have to wrap that in a Runnable and submit it for execution.

You can do that in this way:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doWhateverNeedsToBeDone();
    }
});
```

In Java 8, you can do anything of the following, depending on the extent of the work to be done:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    doWhateverNeedsToBeDone();
});
Platform.runLater(() -> doWhateverNeedsToBeDone());
Platform.runLater(this::doWhateverNeedsToBeDone);
```

The latter only works if `doWhateverNeedsToBeDone()` is a method of `this`.

Comment: I added information, please take a look and tell me if your answer is still valid, then I can give it a try :) also, thanks!

@glglgl

Comment: @TannerSummers Nothing has substantially changed in your question, so the answer still holds. A thread will run "in the background"...

Comment: Dont forget, that if you want to modify gui when background task is done, dont do that directly in that thread but wrap it in `Application.invokeLater()`

Comment: @T.G `Application.invokeLater()`, I guess you wanted to say [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) ??

Comment: can you guys explain Platform.runLater()? I am  having a huge problem with my code and may have to start from scratch, my problem involves chaining gui textbox. See, I have multiple clients connecting in a loop, but there few classes involved deal with this. at this point, one class has a loop taking request from client, and I wish ti update the text box but how does each client connected communicate and edit the class? it is like main -> controller->wrapper class->socket class, now how can socket class edit something in the main class? that is where I am stuck

Comment: @TannerSummers I edited my answer. But for extended information, it might be better to add a new question (or search in the old ones), as it can be better found then...